# differentiability of $f$ on a restriction

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, manifolds

Let's assume that $f:M\to N$, with $M\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$, $N\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is $k$-times differentiable on $M$ (which implies that $M$ is an open set).

In our material we have the statement that:

> If you consider the restriction $f_{|M'}:= f:M'\to N$, where $M' \subseteq M$ and every point $m \in M'$ is a **limit point** of $M'$, then $f_{|M'}$ is also $k$-times differentiable.

I am wondering why it is sufficient that every point in $M'$ only has to be a **limit point** of $M'$ and not an **interior point** of $M'$?

Comment: I'm confused. It states that $M$ is open, and $M'\subseteq M$. Suppose $M$ is bounded, and $M'$ consists of the boundary of $M$. Then $M'$ exclusively contains limit points of $M$ but $M'\not\subseteq M$. Are we not working in the Euclidean topology?

Comment: @R.Burton it says that $M' \subseteq M$ *and* that every point in $M'$ is a limit point of $M$ (not that $M'$ is the collection of all limit points of M). In your case, you can't consider the boundary to begin with.

Comment: @OsamaGhani Doesn't that just leave the interior?

Comment: If $M$ is open as OP says (which I'm thinking might not be what the material actually assumes), then since any point in $M$ is a limit point, being a limit point and an interior point is the same.

Comment: @OsamaGhani So... what's the question then?

Comment: @OsamaGhani a **limit point** is not the same as an **interior point**. Every **interior point** is in fact a **limit point** but not every **limit point** is an **interior point**.

Comment: @Philipp I'm aware but for an open set, every point in an open set is both a limit point and an interior point, for precisely the reason you gave.

Comment: @Philipp Not so - you *could* be working in a topology where every limit point is also an interior point. That's why I asked if we were working in the Euclidean topology.

Comment: @OsamaGhani, but it might be that $m$ is an interior point of $M$ and only a limit point of $M'$.

Comment: @Philipp I understood the statement to mean that "every point $m \in M'$ is a limit point (of $M$)". Is that not what you are assuming? Also can you give more context here. Are $M$ and $N$ subsets of manifolds or of just Euclidean space. You can define $k$-times differentiable for *any* subset of Euclidean space, it does not imply that it is open

Comment: @OsamaGhani I have edited the question. I hope this clarifies the statement.

Comment: I strongly believe the question should refer to every point being a limit point of $M$. Then you can use Ryker's answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482155/restriction-of-smooth-functions , otherwise this statement seems very odd to me. Intuitively, every point of $M'$ being a limit point of $M'$ does not tell me how $M'$ is embedded in $M$.