# Multiplication map on $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ is $C^\infty$

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

In Example 11.16 in Tu's *Introduction to Manifolds* he shows that the multiplication map of $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ is smooth. He begins by saying

> The multiplication map $$\mu: GL(n, \mathbb{R}) \times GL(n, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow GL(n, \mathbb{R})\\ (A,B) \mapsto AB,$$ is clearly $C^\infty$ because $$(AB)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}$$ is a polynomial and hence a $C^\infty$ function of the coordinates $a_{ik}$ and $b_{kj}$. However, one cannot conclude in the same way that the multiplication map $$\bar{\mu}: SL(n, \mathbb{R}) \times SL(n, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow SL(n, \mathbb{R})$$ is $C^\infty$. This is because $\{a_{ij}\}_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}$ is not a coordinate system on $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$; there is one coordinate too many.

And so instead he proves the proposition using another method. However, I am confused on his reasoning as to why we cannot use the polynomial argument to show $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ is smooth. What does he mean?

Comment: Do you understand why $(x,y,z)$ do not form a coordinate system on $S^2\subset \mathbb R^3$?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC So it is purely a dimensional thing and the polynomial argument cannot be salvaged?

Comment: Can you show that if $f \colon X \to Y$ is a smooth map of manifolds and  $f(X') \subset Y'$ for regular submanifolds $X'$ of $X$ and $Y'$ of $Y$ that the restriction of $f$ to a mapping $X' \to Y'$ is a smooth map of manifolds?  The problem you ask about is a special case of this with $X = {\rm GL}_n(\mathbf R) \times {\rm GL}_n(\mathbf R)$ and $Y = {\rm GL}_n(\mathbf R)$.  I checked Tu's book that this is exactly the other method that he uses, and it is a reasonable approach.

Comment: It looks like KCd has an actual proposed solution, but I was going to say "if you covered $SL$ in enough patches, and showed that on each patch some $n^2-1$ of the coordinates formed a local atlas, and that the other co-ordinate was a smooth function of them, then maybe". But it sounds pretty messy, and the general theorem sounds much pleasanter.

Comment: @KCd Yes I was able to follow both of the methods Tu uses in his book.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482155/2838

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M(n,\mathbb R)$ denote the vector space of all real $(n \times n)$-matrices. We can identify $M(n,\mathbb R)$ with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$. The multplication map $\mu$ actually lives on $M(n,\mathbb R)$ and we have
$$\mu : M(n,\mathbb R) \times M(n,\mathbb R) \to M(n,\mathbb R), \mu(A,B)_{ij} = (AB)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj} .$$
All coordinate functions $\mu(A,B)_{ij}$ are polynomials in the coefficients of $A$ and $B$, hence they are $C^\infty$ and so is $\mu$.

Since $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ is an open subset of $M(n,\mathbb R)$, we see that
$$\mu : GL(n,\mathbb R) \times GL(n,\mathbb R) \to GL(n,\mathbb R)$$
is $C^\infty$.

$SL(n,\mathbb R) \subset GL(n,\mathbb R)$ is not open in $M(n,\mathbb R)$, it is a *submanifold* of $M(n,\mathbb R)$ (and also of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$) having codimension $1$. To verify that $\mu$ is $C^\infty$ on $SL(n,\mathbb R)$ we can

- either work with charts (which are not explictly given here; $SL(n,\mathbb R)$ is known to be submanifold  because it is the preimage $\det^{-1}(0)$  of the regular value $0$ of the  $C^\infty$-function $\det: M(n,\mathbb R)  
  \to \mathbb R$)
- or use Theorems 11.14 and 11.15 as Tu does.

Working with charts is very complicated, but certainly it does not give a polynomial representation of $\mu$ in terms of *local coordinates*.